# How to change cell value based on input number

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I want to fill the cells with Character Abbreviation, according to the entering number in that cell.

For example I created the following image Where the **Column L** should be filled with DM, AG, IW, WSW, CW. For this purpose, I used numeric values from 1 to 5 (DM=1, AG=2, IW=3, WSW=4, CW=5). I already
[image: Required Range]

For this, I already entered those values (`AR6:AW17`) as following in the same sheet.
[image]

**Tried**
I used the following  code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim foundVal As Range
    Set foundVal = Range("AR5:AV5").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundVal Is Nothing Then
        Target = foundVal.Offset(1, 0)
        
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```

**Problem**

My question is how can I extend this to put the values to

Column `L` as `AR6:AV6`

Column `M` as `AR7:AW7`

Column `P` as `AR8:AV8`

Column `Q` as `AR14:AU14`

Column `T` as `AR15:AV15`

Column `W` as `AR17:AU17`

**Updated**

The column **Q**, **T**, **W** are added for more consideration please.
and so on, please?

Comment: Could you correct the last part: `AWAV8` is not valid? If it shouldn't have been `AX8` then also add two more, please.

Comment: @VBasic2008, As you requested I corrected my typos and added some more ranges, please.

Comment: This shows now that there is no pattern i.e. the columns and ranges are random. The current presented solution doesn't cover this. I'll fix it shortly.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Resize and Offset in Worksheet Change

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const ColRangesList As String = "L,M,N,P"
    Const RowRangesList As String = "AR5:AV5,AR6:AW6,AR7:AS7;AT8:AX8"
    Const RowOffset As Long = 1
    Const ColOffset As Long = 0
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        Dim ColRanges() As String: ColRanges = Split(ColRangesList, ",")
        Dim RowRanges() As String: RowRanges = Split(RowRangesList, ",")
        Dim crg As Range, rrg As Range, cel As Range
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 0 To UBound(ColRanges)
            Set crg = Columns(ColRanges(n))
            Set rrg = Range(RowRanges(n))
            If Not Intersect(Target, crg) Is Nothing Then
                Set cel = rrg.Find(Target.Value, rrg.Cells(rrg.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Value = cel.Offset(RowOffset, ColOffset).Value
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Even I adjusted the constraints, it only works for first column (`L`). In other columns (`M`, `P`, `Q`, `T`, `W`) it remains as entered number, please.

Comment: Just out-comment or delete `Exit For`.

Comment: Commented, as same not changed. `Const RowOffset As Long = 1`, `Const ColOffset As Long = 0` are same for all column?

Comment: I think `Const RowOffset As Long = 1`, `Const ColOffset As Long = 0` also be changed according to the value entering column. For `Column L` >> `(1, 0)`, For `Column M` >> `(2, 0)`, For `Column P` >> `(3, 0)`, For `Column Q` >> `(4, 0)`, For `Column T` >> `(5, 0)`, For `Column W` >> `(6, 0)`

Comment: Then try `RowOffset + n`.

Comment: `RowOffset` is constant, then how it be possible? I changed as said no change, please.